# Android - FragmentPagerAdapter and ViewPager inside Fragment inside FragmentActivity with FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a FragmentActivity which hosts a FragmentTabHost.
The goal is to have swipeable content in the first tab.

So the first tab hosts a FragmentPagerAdapter and ViewPager.
The app compiles fine but nothing is shown in the first tab and it is not swipeable.

I'm still new to android and I'm stuck. I hope that someone can help me.
Here is my relevant code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnTabChangeListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initTabs();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void initTabs()
    {
        FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),R.id.realtabcontent);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Übersicht").setIndicator("Übersicht"), OverviewFragment.class, null); // <- shall contain swipeable content
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Einstellungen").setIndicator("Einstellungen"), SettingsFragment.class, null); // <- 'static' content

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }
...
}
```

OverviewFragment (shall host the swipeable content):

```
public class OverviewFragment extends Fragment 
{
    ViewPager _pagerView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        _pagerView = (ViewPager)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_overview, container, false).findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        initPager();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_overview, container, false);
    }

    private void initPager()
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        PageAdapter pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(fm);
        _pagerView.setAdapter(pageAdapter);     
    }        
}
```

PageAdapter:

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
    {
        super(fm);
    }   


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) 
    {
        MemoryFragment m1 = new MemoryFragment();
        return m1;
    }    

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

MemmoryFragment (the fragment that should be shown as a page in the FragmentPagerController):

```
public class MemoryFragment extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.memmory, container,false);
        TextView tv = (TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewTest);
        tv.setText("You are viewing the page Swipe Horizontally left / right");
        return v;
    }
}
```

I know that this code shows nothing meaningful. It should just show 5 swipeable pages with the same text for the start.

Comment: Can you show us your android layout xml file ?

Comment: In initPager() of `OverviewFragment` class try use `getFragmentManager()` or `gerParentFragment().getFragmentManger()` I hope it would help you..